# Why do we mention -1 in model.matrix function in R ? is it for one hot encoding or does it have any other reason?

Tags: r, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

Why do we mention `-1` in the formula of `model.matrix` function from the `stats`package.

```
training_matrix <-model.matrix(Survived ~.-1, data = training)
```

The standard `titanic` dataset is used in this case.

There is also documentation that says that one hot encoding can be performed using `model.matrix` with `-1` notation, provided we have declared the factors and numeric in the dataset properly.

The code is as follows

```
data_1_matrix <-model.matrix(~.-1, data = data_1)
```

What does this `-1` do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -1 ensures there is no constant in your model matrix. If you would use

```
training_matrix <-model.matrix(Survived ~., data = training)
```

There is a column of ones included and one category is omitted in the model matrix, to ensure your model will not suffer from multicollinearity.

It is up to the user what is preferable: If you use a constant, there will be a 'reference class' in your model. If you don't, there is no reference class.

Comment: You should always include the intercept. If you don't like treatment contrasts, use different contrasts, but don't exclude the intercept.

Comment: @Roland Can you elaborate on what do you refer to by the term intercept here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M Sure, the intercept is the parameter corresponding to the column of ones in the model matrix.